# while passing multiple integer value together getting error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary]  
 @locations integer 
AS
    BEGIN 
..............
.............
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (@locations))
```

my locid field is integer
this locid coming from my listbox.if i select one item 1 locid will come.if i select 2 item 2 locid will come..
I've got a ListBox which populates the @locations parameter (an integer), I took my listbox value like this

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
 Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim locid As Integer
        If cnt > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To cnt - 1
                Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
                locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
                list.Add(locid)
            Next
End If
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("T_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
        cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd23
        da.Fill(ds)
```

if the code reach here i am getting error like this:

```
"Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32
```

i know am getting error in this line

```
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list)
```

but i want go the parameter to stored procedure like 1,2,3 only i am using vb.net. what i have to change in my code..any help is great appreciate ..

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is an integer, not a list of integers.

If you want to pass a list of variable length, you should use `table valued parameters`

See http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/

Comment: so where i have to change?

Comment: if you don't mind..can u show me how to do? i am struggling to find out solution of this last 2 days.

Comment: @user2878851 Follow the link. It's all there.

Comment: sir i try to give  @locations loc_id READONLY , but showing error:Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type loc_id.

Comment: i mean i try to give my @locations as table value parameter..but getting error